# How to add code to initialize sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I use codefirst and I use Elmah.
I recreated every time the database, you must manually add the code from the file:

```
/*

   ELMAH - Error Logging Modules and Handlers for ASP.NET
   Copyright (c) 2004-9 Atif Aziz. All rights reserved.

    Author(s):

        Atif Aziz, http://www.raboof.com
        Phil Haacked, http://haacked.com

   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.

*/

-- ELMAH DDL script for Microsoft SQL Server 2000 or later.

-- $Id: SQLServer.sql 677 2009-09-29 18:02:39Z azizatif $

DECLARE @DBCompatibilityLevel INT
DECLARE @DBCompatibilityLevelMajor INT
DECLARE @DBCompatibilityLevelMinor INT

SELECT 
    @DBCompatibilityLevel = cmptlevel 
FROM 
    master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE 
    name = DB_NAME()

IF @DBCompatibilityLevel <> 80
BEGIN

    SELECT @DBCompatibilityLevelMajor = @DBCompatibilityLevel / 10, 
           @DBCompatibilityLevelMinor = @DBCompatibilityLevel % 10

    PRINT N'
    ===========================================================================
    WARNING! 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    This script is designed for Microsoft SQL Server 2000 (8.0) but your 
    database is set up for compatibility with version ' 
    + CAST(@DBCompatibilityLevelMajor AS NVARCHAR(80)) 
    + N'.' 
    + CAST(@DBCompatibilityLevelMinor AS NVARCHAR(80)) 
    + N'. Although 
    the script should work with later versions of Microsoft SQL Server, 
    you can ensure compatibility by executing the following statement:

    ALTER DATABASE [' 
    + DB_NAME() 
    + N'] 
    SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80

    If you are hosting ELMAH in the same database as your application 
    database and do not wish to change the compatibility option then you 
    should create a separate database to host ELMAH where you can set the 
    compatibility level more freely.

    If you continue with the current setup, please report any compatibility 
    issues you encounter over at:

    http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/list

    ===========================================================================
'
END
GO

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        TABLES
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error]
(
    [ErrorId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Application] NVARCHAR(60)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Host]        NVARCHAR(50)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Type]        NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Source]      NVARCHAR(60)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Message]     NVARCHAR(500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [User]        NVARCHAR(50)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [StatusCode]  INT NOT NULL,
    [TimeUtc]     DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Sequence]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AllXml]      NTEXT COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
) 
ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ELMAH_Error] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ErrorId]) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [DF_ELMAH_Error_ErrorId] DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [ErrorId]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ELMAH_Error_App_Time_Seq] ON [dbo].[ELMAH_Error] 
(
    [Application]   ASC,
    [TimeUtc]       DESC,
    [Sequence]      DESC
) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        STORED PROCEDURES                                                      
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_GetErrorXml]
(
    @Application NVARCHAR(60),
    @ErrorId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT 
        [AllXml]
    FROM 
        [ELMAH_Error]
    WHERE
        [ErrorId] = @ErrorId
    AND
        [Application] = @Application

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_GetErrorsXml]
(
    @Application NVARCHAR(60),
    @PageIndex INT = 0,
    @PageSize INT = 15,
    @TotalCount INT OUTPUT
)
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @FirstTimeUTC DATETIME
    DECLARE @FirstSequence INT
    DECLARE @StartRow INT
    DECLARE @StartRowIndex INT

    SELECT 
        @TotalCount = COUNT(1) 
    FROM 
        [ELMAH_Error]
    WHERE 
        [Application] = @Application

    -- Get the ID of the first error for the requested page

    SET @StartRowIndex = @PageIndex * @PageSize + 1

    IF @StartRowIndex <= @TotalCount
    BEGIN

        SET ROWCOUNT @StartRowIndex

        SELECT  
            @FirstTimeUTC = [TimeUtc],
            @FirstSequence = [Sequence]
        FROM 
            [ELMAH_Error]
        WHERE   
            [Application] = @Application
        ORDER BY 
            [TimeUtc] DESC, 
            [Sequence] DESC

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SET @PageSize = 0

    END

    -- Now set the row count to the requested page size and get
    -- all records below it for the pertaining application.

    SET ROWCOUNT @PageSize

    SELECT 
        errorId     = [ErrorId], 
        application = [Application],
        host        = [Host], 
        type        = [Type],
        source      = [Source],
        message     = [Message],
        [user]      = [User],
        statusCode  = [StatusCode], 
        time        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [TimeUtc], 126) + 'Z'
    FROM 
        [ELMAH_Error] error
    WHERE
        [Application] = @Application
    AND
        [TimeUtc] <= @FirstTimeUTC
    AND 
        [Sequence] <= @FirstSequence
    ORDER BY
        [TimeUtc] DESC, 
        [Sequence] DESC
    FOR
        XML AUTO

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_LogError]
(
    @ErrorId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @Application NVARCHAR(60),
    @Host NVARCHAR(30),
    @Type NVARCHAR(100),
    @Source NVARCHAR(60),
    @Message NVARCHAR(500),
    @User NVARCHAR(50),
    @AllXml NTEXT,
    @StatusCode INT,
    @TimeUtc DATETIME
)
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT
    INTO
        [ELMAH_Error]
        (
            [ErrorId],
            [Application],
            [Host],
            [Type],
            [Source],
            [Message],
            [User],
            [AllXml],
            [StatusCode],
            [TimeUtc]
        )
    VALUES
        (
            @ErrorId,
            @Application,
            @Host,
            @Type,
            @Source,
            @Message,
            @User,
            @AllXml,
            @StatusCode,
            @TimeUtc
        )

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

I execute this code automatically?
I tried to use `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` but I get lots of errors of the form:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@ErrorId".
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@TotalCount".
Must declare the scalar variable "@PageIndex".
Must declare the scalar variable "@TotalCount".
Must declare the scalar variable "@Application".
Must declare the scalar variable "@PageSize".
Must declare the scalar variable "@PageSize".
Must declare the scalar variable "@Application".
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@ErrorId".
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

Comment: would it be a big hassle to move the elmah db into a seperate db?? that way, you don't have the hassle of losing all your logged events everytime as well. simple as just adding an additional connectionstring into the web.config

Comment: elmah is only the top of the iceberg. I have other scripts for static databases.

Comment: ok, i guess what i'm saying is that surely best practice here would be that only your code first db is affected by all of this (i.e. recreation of the db on the model changing). all other tables unrelated to that should be in an ApplicationServices db or similar. this is certainly how we do it in our shop.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this migration, bearing in mind that it expects all GO statements to be on a single line and that the file uses \r\n line endings. I installed Elmah using the *elmah.sqlserver* NuGet package, which drops the SqlServer.sql file in the appropriate location. You will need to change the resource name to match your project.

```
public partial class Elmah : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        var sqlStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.App_Readme.Elmah.SqlServer.sql");
        using(var sqlStreamReader = new StreamReader(sqlStream))
        {
            string sqlScript = sqlStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            ExecuteSqlScript(sqlScript);
        }
    }

    void ExecuteSqlScript(string sqlScript)
    {
        string[] sql = sqlScript.Split(new[] {"\r\nGO\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var sqlCommand in sql)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sqlCommand))
                Sql(sqlCommand);
        }
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("ELMAH_Error");
        Sql("DROP PROCEDURE ELMAH_GetErrorXml");
        Sql("DROP PROCEDURE ELMAH_GetErrorsXml");
        Sql("DROP PROCEDURE ELMAH_LogError");
    }
}
```

I

Comment: To get this to work I needed to change the script's build action to "Embedded Resource", as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068736/cant-load-a-manifest-resource-with-getmanifestresourcestream Great answer though, thanks.

Comment: How can I update the DB with this new manually created migration? When I execute 'update-database', I get this: "The specified target migration 'Elmah' does not exist. Ensure that target migration refers to an existing migration id"

Comment: I only used a string with SQL (so didn't put it in a separate file). Removed the \r\n and it's working great. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

just to formalize my comment to the OP as an answer;

I think that the best practice here would be that only your code-first db should be affected by any radical changes (i.e. recreation of the db on the model changing). All other tables unrelated to that should be in an ApplicationServices db or similar and NOT in the core db. That way you don't create a support nightmare everytime you need to update your model with a simple property or data type change. Plus, you do of course end up losing the entire history of your logging (and other) db tables every time you make a change.

So, in a word, I think you're tackling the wrong problem with a potentially inappropriate solution.

This is certainly how we do it in our shop and in previous projects that I've worked on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a series of SQL commands separated by GO statements (which aren't strictly T-SQL commands)

You can use SQL Managment Studio to execute the script, or the command line tool SQLCMD.exe

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should run that many batches on ExecuteSqlCommand.

Why don't you simply execute it on SSMS?

Comment: I did not understand what you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse your script, split it to separate SQL commands and execute each one of them individually through `SqlCommand`. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

The script requires you to separate the batches (`GO` is the batch separator) and send each batch individually to SQL Server. I actually have a sample project [dbutilsqlcmd](http://code.google.com/p/dbutilsqlcmd/) that does just that, and also supports more of the sqlcmd extensions like `:setvar` and `$(variable)` replacement in the script, which can be quite useful at deployment.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a nuget package that will initialize the Elmah table and procs for you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.SqlServer.EFInitializer/. Add it to your web project. It will then use EF code first to create it for you. It adds an Initializer to your App_Start folder so you actually don't have to add any code. It will add a migration to your database to ensure it only gets added once.