# Entity Framework 5 Migrations creating procedures/functions

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, powershell, entity-framework-5

I'm creating SQL procedures in Entity Framework by using `Sql` methods in the migration. For example in an `Up()` I'm doing

```
Sql(@"SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction
...
GO");
```

Now my problem is with the `GO`s: if I want to be able to script my migrations (for using on a live server) I need the `GO`s in the generated script, otherwise it doesn't work. However for running `Update-Database` without the `-script` option (for use while developing), it gets upset about the `GO`s.

I've found some partial answers:

[How to add code to initialize sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621322/how-to-add-code-to-initialize-sql-database) 
The answer by Bart provides a method to call to divide the statement up into multiple `Sql` calls. The problem with this is that it affects the generated script when running with the `-script` option, so back to square 1.

[How can I override SQL scripts generated by MigratorScriptingDecorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930259/how-can-i-override-sql-scripts-generated-by-migratorscriptingdecorator) Also looks like it could be useful.

My question is therefore: is there either a way to know whether you're running the migration with the `-script` option, or a better way to script my SQL procedures in the migrations?

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a similar question where someone actually gave me an awesome answer

[here is the answer to it. I hope it helps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105716/adding-go-statements-to-entity-framework-migrations)

basically you have to alter your configuration file of your migration configurator