# Adding 'GO' statements to Entity Framework migrations

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

So I have an application with a ton of migrations made by Entity framework.
We want to get a script for all the migrations at once and using the `-Script` tag does work fine.

However...it does not add `GO` statements in the SQL giving us problems like `Alter view should be the first statement in a batch file...`

I have been searching around and manually adding `Sql("GO");` help with this problem but **only** for the entire script. When I use the package console manager again it returns an exception.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'GO'.
```

Is there a way to add these `GO` tags **only** when using the `-Script` tag?
If not, what is a good approach for this?

Note: we have also tried having multiple files but since we have so many migrations, this is near impossible to maintain every time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to change the SQL Generated by entity framework migrations you can create a new `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator`

We have done this to add a GO statement before and after the migration history:

```
public  class MigrationScriptBuilder: SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.InsertHistoryOperation insertHistoryOperation)
    {
        Statement("GO");

        base.Generate(insertHistoryOperation);

        Statement("GO");

    }
}
```

then add in the `Configuration` constructor (in the  `Migrations` folder of the project where you DbContext is) so that it uses this new sql generator:

```
[...]
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<PMA.Dal.PmaContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new MigrationScriptBuilder());
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
[...]
```

So now when you generate a script using the -Script tag, you can see that the `insert into [__MigrationHistory]` is surrounded by `GO`

Alternatively in your implementation of `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` you can override any part of the script generation, the `InsertHistoryOperation` was suitable for us.

Comment: Works perfectly when using the `-Script` tag. I have to comment out the `SetSqlGenerator(".....` line however when I dont use it because otherwise I got the exception again. This however saves me a ton of time because it is just commenting out a line in stead of adding `Sql("GO");` everywhere. Thanks!

Comment: I can't find InsertHistoryOperation.  Which assembly is it in?

Comment: Ah I think it's renamed in EF 6 to HistoryOperation

Answer (score 19):

If you are trying to alter your view using `Sql("Alter View dbo.Foos As etc")`, then you can avoid the `should be the first statement in a batch file` error without adding `GO` statements by putting the sql inside an `EXEC` command:

`Sql("EXEC('Alter View dbo.Foos As etc')")`

Comment: This thing allows to fill tables and columns right after creation. Great!

Comment: Where is the EXEC function defined please? I am unable to find it.

Comment: @MathuSumMut It is standard Sql. I had omitted the quotation marks needed around the Sql string. I've edited the answer to correct the error

Comment: This should be the accepted answers. It is also stated here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12911#issuecomment-831447488

Answer (score 10):

Turn out the concept exist deep in the `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` as an optional argument for `Statement(sql, batchTerminator)`. Here is something based on Skyp idea.  It works both in -script mode or not.  The GOs are for different operations than for Skyp only because our needs are a little different.  You then need to register this class in the `Configuration` as per Skyp instructions.

```
    public class MigrationScriptBuilder : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
    {
        private string Marker = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //To cheat on the check null or empty of the base generator

        protected override void Generate(AlterProcedureOperation alterProcedureOperation)
        {
            SqlGo();
            base.Generate(alterProcedureOperation);
            SqlGo();
        }
        protected override void Generate(CreateProcedureOperation createProcedureOperation)
        {
            SqlGo();
            base.Generate(createProcedureOperation);
            SqlGo();
        }
        protected override void Generate(SqlOperation sqlOperation)
        {
            SqlGo();
            base.Generate(sqlOperation);
        }

        private void SqlGo()
        {
            Statement(Marker, batchTerminator: "GO");
        }

        public override IEnumerable<MigrationStatement> Generate(IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> migrationOperations, string providerManifestToken)
        {
            var result = new List<MigrationStatement>();
            var statements = base.Generate(migrationOperations, providerManifestToken);

            bool pendingBatchTerminator = false;
            foreach (var item in statements)
            {
                if(item.Sql == Marker && item.BatchTerminator == "GO")
                {
                    pendingBatchTerminator = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(pendingBatchTerminator)
                    {
                        item.BatchTerminator = "GO";
                        pendingBatchTerminator = false;
                    }
                    result.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me! I was looking for a way that works both with and without -script argument. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me when EF6 was inexplicably removing a go statement from the end of my stored procedure creation script being inserted via SqlResource.  The magic of EF is not something I'm fond of.

Comment: hm, interesting, this works perfectly when using ``update-database -script`` however in an Azure Deployment Group Task ``Generate migration SQL script`` instead of ``GO`` terminator ``EXECUTE('<GUIDSTRING>')``-statements appear in the generated code

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to add /**/ before the GO statement.

Answer (score -3):

Just replace the current statement with a .Replace("GO", "");