# 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch. Entity Framework Code First

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have some inline SQL Scripts (functions and stored procedures) generated with Entity framework , Code first approach.

> Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0

With the above command I get SQL Script file that I execute on test or production.

However I cannot run the generated script because of the following error:

```
'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a  query batch.
```

The script is generated as:

IF @CurrentMigration < '201410150019333_CreatefnGenerateRequestCode'
BEGIN
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGenerateRequestCode] (
    @userID varchar(max)
    )
    RETURNS varchar(14)
    as

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  have to generate your code and execute it as dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = 
'
IF OBJECT_ID(''fn_Test'') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION fn_Test
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_Test(@a INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN @a
END
'
IF 1 = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC(@Sql)
END
```

Comment: Thank you! End up going to the path that I did not want to at first place. Still better than that error.

Comment: @elle0087. Yes it is as long as you embed the sql file in your assembly.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the

> should be the first statement in a batch file

error without adding GO statements by putting the sql inside an EXEC command:

```
Sql(EXEC('BEGIN CREATE FUNCTION etc'))
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20352867/150342

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the previous statements, to the CREATE FUNCTION, on a first EXEC statement and then run the CREATE FUNCTION into another EXEC statement.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(3000) = ''

SET @query += 'SET ANSI_NULLS ON' + CHAR(10) 

SET @query += 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON' + CHAR(10) 

SET @query +=  'IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                           FROM   sys.objects
                           WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[' + @DB_Name + '_InitCap]'')
                                  AND type IN ( N''FN'', N''IF'', N''TF'', N''FS'', N''FT'' ))
                  DROP FUNCTION [dbo].['+ @DB_Name + '_InitCap]' + CHAR(10)

EXEC sp_executesql @query

SET @query = 'CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[' + @DB_Name + '_InitCap] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(4000) AS' + CHAR(10)
....
....
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```