# c# - why always null get resource embedded file in sfx folder?

Tags: c#, stream, embedded-resource

why always get null get resource embedded file in my project 'Kriptografi'. My folder is sfx. I tried file in build action 'embedded resource'. Anyone can resolve it ?
Thanks

```
void test() 
{
    var ConfigXml = "Kriptografi.sfx.Config.xml";
    Stream cfg = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(ConfigXml);
    if (cfg == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing");
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exist"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: consider this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068736/cant-load-a-manifest-resource-with-getmanifestresourcestream .The second answer might help you

Comment: I have not checked any embedded resources. Thanks