# Loading the xsl file using getmanifestresourcestream throwing exception value cannot be null and parameter:stream

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I created a xsl file and i loaded using getmanifestresourcestream();
    showing exception like value cannot be null and parameter:stream.
    here is the code i used can anyone help me where is the problem?

```
string path ="EDI.Generator.dbtoX12850canonical.xsl";
Stream strm1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(path);
StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(strm1);
string myXslCanonical = reader1.ReadToEnd();
reader1.Close();
```

when I debug the code the stream is not reading the xsl file and showing null in strm1 object .

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068736/cant-load-a-manifest-resource-with-getmanifestresourcestream

Comment: i tried but not working.Is the xsl file is empty or is there is any link for the xsl file

Comment: make sure your `path` really point to the real location of te file.