# Can't read html file in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm freaking out with this problem. I want to read the data of a HTML in c#. So, I have an HTML file in the same Class Library in Visual Studio. [Visual Studio Class Library distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31O2T.png)

So, I want to use **Stream Reader** to read the file, with the assembly.

`StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("proyectoHADS.LIbreriaClase.EmailTemplate.html"));`

But, this returns a **null**, so I use the `GetManifestResourceNames` to check if it exists, but it doesn't because the array is empty. I don't know why I can't get the HTML. The entire code is here:

`namespace LibreriaClase`

```
public class EnviarCorreo { 

    public void enviarCorreo(String correo)
    {
        ....

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("proyectoHADS.LIbreriaClase.EmailTemplate.html"));
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();`
```

Comment: Does the file have to be part of the class library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't load a manifest resource with GetManifestResourceStream()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068736/cant-load-a-manifest-resource-with-getmanifestresourcestream)

Comment: Is the file set as EmbeddedResource?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code snippet can help you:

```
public void enviarCorreo(String correo)
{        
  ....
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
using( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("proyectoHADS.LIbreriaClase.EmailTemplate.html"));
{
 String line = String.Emtpy;
 while( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null )
 {
  Console.WriteLine(line);
 }
}
```

By the way dont forget check `proyectoHADS.LIbreriaClase.EmailTemplate.html` line is it `null` or not.