# How to embed multilanguage resx on main assembly?

Tags: c#, resources, multilingual

I have a multilanguage class library containing several .resx files. Instead of embedding the resources files on the main assembly, it creates a folder per language containing a `assembly.resources.dll` assembly

Resx files are contained on a folder named `Resources` and they are marked as embedded resources.

Is there any simple way to have all resx files embedded on my class library assembly?

Comment: refer this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793256/how-to-embed-multilanguage-resx-or-resources-files-in-single-exe

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: Thanks! I found the same question googling for this, but I was looking for something simpler if possible.

Comment: oh ok. I like the satellite assembly way - can update or add support for new languages without changing the main assembly. Do share if you find a different way of doing this.